# Correct way of calling a postgres function using node-postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, node-postgres

I am trying to workout how to call a postgres function using [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com/) but unfortunately cannot find any examples.

I am seeing examples on the web like this but this is based off a different package (pg-promise), which I am not using:

```
db.func('inserttask', ['task_name','task_type'])
```

I am also seeing examples like this as well:

```
const query= `SELECT inserttask($1, $2)`;        
result= await pool.query(query, ['task_name','task_type']);
```

I haven't as yet tried these as I wanted to check which approach is correct, when using node-postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the link you provided:

```
const res = await client.query('SELECT $1::text as message', ['Hello world!'])
```

Isn't it good enough?

If you have official docs that answer your question, it is usually the one to trust.

Comment: Is this actually for a function call?

Comment: I don't think there is any difference, just try.